# php cake Controller redirect fails on external URL or with jQuery / AJAX

Tags: jquery, cakephp, exception, redirect

I have an app built in Cake-PHP that works great. I have a large number of dynamically generated forms which take a bit of CPU server side, so what I do is serve a main page with a bunch of empty DIVs and load each form on demand with a jQuery.ajax GET call instead of a page-level URL, and send the form back in a similar manner with a jQuery POST. All of this works great.

I also have session management with a timeout and login screen, and the PHP code is set up to throw a 302 from the Controller with `$this->redirect('/login',302)` ... this works fine when the request comes from the browser, e.g. if I put up a little form and submit it with a plain `INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT` button. Response time is < 100ms.

If I submit an ostensibly identical request using $.ajax() the behaviour is totally different ... with the same code calling $this->redirect throws an exception from within the cake code, which looks like this ... the whole thing is ~30MB so I didn't include it all :)

```
MissingControllerException Object
(
[_messageTemplate:protected] => Controller class %s could not be found.
[_attributes:protected] => Array
    (
        [class] => Controller
        [plugin] => 
    )

[_responseHeaders:protected] => 
[message:protected] => Controller class Controller could not be found.
[string:Exception:private] => 
[code:protected] => 404
[file:protected] => /var/www/bfdave/bf/lib-2.3.1/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php
[line:protected] => 156
[trace:Exception:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => /var/www/bfdave/bf/lib-2.3.1/Cake/Core/Object.php
                [line] => 103
                [function] => dispatch
                [class] => Dispatcher
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => CakeRequest Object
                            (
                                [params] => Array
                                    (
                                        [plugin] => 
                                        [controller] => 
                                        [action] => 
                                        [named] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                        [pass] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                        [autoRender] => 1
                                        [return] => 0
                                        [bare] => 
                                        [requested] => 1
                                    )
```

Comment: Figured it out .... like most of the Cake documentation it's a bit vague - it says you can use an absolute URL, it does not say explicity that it has to come back to the same Cake system. Attempting to use any other URL results in the above exception.

I can work around this but candidly it's a bit stupid / trying to be too clever IMHO.

Comment: There is a bit more to it, and I was not dreaming when I believed it worked differently with different clients:

1. The function name and acceptance of HTTP status codes is a bit misleading to say the least.

2. The URL for `Controller::redirect(url, code)` must map back to the same Cake installation per the Router etc. otherwise it barfs the above exception.

3. When I do a POST from the browser and redirect to another Cake URL, it works fine and throws a 302 at the browser.

Comment: 4. When I POST to the same URL from jQuery, it runs in a loop and keeps calling my code `MyController::beforeFilter` with the original URL over and over again. I have no idea why.

Comment: The workaround is to bypass Cake entirely and use the PHP basic functions to respond:

`header('Location: http://whatever.you.want/', false, 302);
die();`

Comment: This sounds to me like you forgot to map URL `/login` to controller action. Read more about it [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html). Might look like: `Router::connect(
    '/login',
    array('controller' => 'auth', 'action' => 'create')
);` based on your structure.

Comment: No, I'm talking about throwing redirects to URLs which (horror, I know) live outside the Cake framework.

Comment: Ok, are you using hardcoded URL in `$.ajax()` call or are you referencing `form.action`? In either way, what is the requested URL for AJAX and what is the form action?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with AJAX and browsers, it's a CakePHP bug / misfeature. In a nutshell:

In Java `HttpServletResponse.redirect('http://foo.com/')` throws a redirect to foo.com

Cake's `Controller::redirect('http://foo.com/')` generates an error

Comment: Well, I thought your problem was that both form and ajax were calling same controller action, but only via form request could you be redirected. Now it's more clear and I believe the error is yours, not Cake. Could you try to `debug(Router::url('http://foo.com', true));` in AppController::beforeFilter() and post what you see? This is the URL cake will try to redirect you. 1. Missing controller exception might be related to wrong path configuration, so double check webroot/index.php. 2. note there is also callback Controller::beforeRedirect, which might mess things up

Comment: I guess I am "wrong" for expecting Cake's redirect function to work like every other redirect function in the world, i.e. to return a 302 to the browser. However, Cake is IMHO wrong for using this non-standard behaviour, and given that it does so, they should document the heck out of it, i.e. in bold at the top of the method explanation, "Cake::redirect does not send HTTP redirects (302)" and "the URL passed to Cake::redirect must be within the same Cake framework and not an external web site"

Comment: Yeah, you can blame cake, but most likely it is your code that is causing this:) Cake is just passing your URL to PHP `header` function. See [code](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/source-class-CakeResponse.html#390). The default status code for location header is 302, but you can alter it, as you saw in cookbook. However, if you read PHP manual: _"Location:" header, not only does it send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a REDIRECT (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code has already been set._ So check what headers are really set.

Comment: The CAKE installation we have here edits the URLs passed to redirect. Simple enough workaround, use PHP function instead. But it's weird.